# Core Data with in-memory store

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I want to use Core Data as a cache for a larger dataset on a database server. 
Not all data will be in memory.

When thinking about this further 2 questions came to mind:

1. Can faulting (for example for 1-n relationships) be used with the in-memory persistent store, and if so, how do you a catch a fault firing?
2. A Core data managed object context has a staleness interval. Is this also applicable to a in-memory store?

Or should I use a NSAtomicStore for this purpose?

Comment: Almost sounds like what you really want to do is implement your own storage layer: managed objects that fault back to a persistent store that is your database server.

Comment: Yes, but the only way to do this is the NSAtomicStore (in Mac OS X 10.5+) and then you have to load everything in at once AFAIK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first question suggests you misinterpreted the intention of `NSInMemoryStore` type persistent stores. They are the *persistent* store part of the Core Data stack. Faulting is something that happens when you bring instances into a managed object context; a fault is created which fires and populates itself from the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s cache or the underlying persistent store when fired. An in-memory store does not change the faulting relationship. Obviously, it won't really help your problem, however since you'll have to *persist* all the data to memory. In-memory stores are really appropriate for (1) testing (they're fast) and (2) scratch core data stacks in which you want to use Core Data's object graph management without having to persist anything to disk.

In response to you second question, the answer is YES. The staleness interval applies to the context, not to the persistent store.

So, is Core Data appropriate for caching data from a remote database server? Not really. Although Bill Bumgarner (an Apple engineer) has hinted that it's possible, I've found it much easier in my own code to separate the caching from the Core Data object graph management. It's still very nice to use Core Data to manage an object graph and for ease of binding to a Controller/UI layer(s). So my strategy is pull data from the database server and cache it in my own data structure (the libcache and NSCache in OS X 10.6 might make a very good starting point). Then decide what you want in your object graph and migrate that into a Core Data stack (backed by an in-memory persistent store). You'll have to handle change notification or polling from the database server yourself. When the data from the database changes (or the user query changes, etc.), I just tell all editors to finish editing, then wipe the context and rebuild it from the (possibly) updated cache.

Comment: You are right, I thought for some reason the in-memory store would handle thinks differently with the contexts (to prevent having the object in memory twice). But this is of course not the case.

I also did have a look at NSAtomicStore to load stuff into the persistence store coordinator's cache. The problem I see is that I have no way of controlling the staleness of the objects (I don't want to load the whole database in the cache). I want more of less the same behavior as the Sqlite store.

With NSCache I can see you set a limit to the max number of object sin the cache. That's nice.

Comment: @barrywark, according to you answer, am I correct that bullet 2 "scratch core data stacks in which you want to use Core Data's object graph management without having to persist anything to disk" means "if you want to store core data stack in memory before saving to disk in case of unavailability of disk or storage"? So, in some cases, if I want to store data in memory ( because disk is unavailable ), I could store data in memory.